Diffrent hex dump values of function for C and Python code
This is my example C code for dumping MessageBoxA from user32.dll:
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void DumpFun(HANDLE process, LPVOID address, SIZE_T dump_size) {
    BYTE *buffer = (BYTE *)malloc(dump_size);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        return;
    }

    SIZE_T bytes_read;
    if (ReadProcessMemory(process, address, buffer, dump_size, &bytes_read)) {
        printf("Dumping function bytes at address 0x%p:\n", address);
        for (SIZE_T i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++) {
            printf("%02X ", buffer[i]);
            if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0) printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("ReadProcessMemory failed with error %lu\n", GetLastError());
    }

    free(buffer);
}

int main() {
    HMODULE user32 = LoadLibraryA("user32.dll");
    if (!user32) {
        printf("Failed to load user32.dll\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FARPROC fun = GetProcAddress(user32, "MessageBoxA");
    if (!fun) {
        printf("Failed to get address of MessageBoxA\n");
        FreeLibrary(user32);
        return 1;
    }

    SIZE_T dump_size = 100;
    DumpFun(GetCurrentProcess(), fun, dump_size);
    FreeLibrary(user32);

    return 0;
}

And this is output:
Dumping function bytes at address 0x75C91600:
8B FF 55 8B EC 83 3D B4 6C CB 75 00 74 22 64 A1
18 00 00 00 BA FC 80 CB 75 8B 48 24 33 C0 F0 0F
B1 0A 85 C0 75 0A C7 05 20 6D CB 75 01 00 00 00
6A FF 6A 00 FF 75 14 FF 75 10 FF 75 0C FF 75 08
...

But when I try with this python code:
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32.dll')
message_box_a = user32.MessageBoxA
message_box_a_addr = ctypes.cast(message_box_a, ctypes.c_void_p).value
print(f'Address of MessageBoxA: {hex(message_box_a_addr)}')
num_bytes = 100
buffer = (ctypes.c_ubyte * num_bytes)()
ctypes.memmove(buffer, message_box_a_addr, num_bytes)
byte_array = bytearray(buffer)
hex_bytes = ' '.join(f'{byte:02x}' for byte in byte_array)
print(f'Bytes of MessageBoxA: {hex_bytes}')

This is output
Address of MessageBoxA: 0x7ffa2749a710
Bytes of MessageBoxA: 48 83 ec 38 45 33 db 44 39 1d 02 8c 03 00 74 2e 65 48 8b 04 25 30 00 00 00 4c 8b 50 48 33 c0 f0 4c 0f b1 15 78 97 03 00 4c 8b 15 79 97 03 00 41 8d 43 01 4c 0f 44 d0 4c 89 15 6a 97 03 00 83 4c 24 28 ff 66 44 89 5c 24 20 e8 e2 02 00 00 48 83 c4 38 c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 48 83 ec 38

When I check user32.dll with HxD I see that output from python is correct, but not from C?

You should tag this windows.  Don't cast the void * from malloc() in C.

Why did you truncate the first output at 64 bytes but not the 2nd?

In original C code I was looking for a RET as a mark for end of dump. But main point is why there are two addresses (C: 0x75C91600 vs python: 0x7ffa2749a710), it should be the same?

The address, I imagine, is impacted by address randomization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization and for the content either your programs are not comparable.  I don't use windows so I can't reproduce this debug this for you.  As I said you should tag it with your os so someone with more relevant experience have an easier time finding your question.

Is your C code 32-bit (based on %p printing a 32-bit value) vs. 64-bit Python?  32-bit C would be using c:\windows\syswow64\user32.dll.

I have added windows tag. Regarding ASRL I was thinking that it doesn’t affect “system libraries” like user32.dll, kernel.dll etc.

ASLR is seeded at boot time. After that the system will (attempt to) load the same image at the same address. The 32-bit vs. 64-bit mismatch is much more likely.

I tried with both path's LoadLibraryA("C:/Windows/System32/user32.dll") and LoadLibraryA("C:/Windows/SysWOW64/user32.dll") and the result is same “0x8B 0xFF 0x55 0x8B 0xEC..”

You cannot load a 64-bit module into a 32-bit process (or vice versa). It doesn't matter which path you use: If your binary is 32-bit you can load a 32-bit DLL. Besides, the hex dump from your C application decompiles to somewhat meaningless code (when interpreted as 64-bit code), but looks legit when interpreted as 32-bit code.

@MladjanJovanovic It's just a difference between the output at 32-bit:https://i.sstatic.net/vTWh7rYo.png and 64-bit:https://i.sstatic.net/IYi0c6rW.png.  Loading C:WindowsSysWow64user32.dll. Successfully shows that you had run it in 32-bit. Because you can't load a 32-bit module directly into a 64-bit process, otherwise it will return error 193.

@MladjanJovanovic Does it solve your problem?

In conclusion, It's just a difference between the output at 32-bit:

and 64-bit:

Loading C:\Windows\SysWow64\user32.dll successfully shows that op had run it in 32-bit.
Can't load a 32-bit module directly into a 64-bit process, also as @
IInspectable said vice versa.
